# Question about segue and NSViewController

Tags: swift, storyboard, segue, nsviewcontroller

I am new in Swift and have a question.

I have ViewController for my customer  with a included a tableView that list their past invoice.  When I double click on an invoice, it open the Invoice ViewController that detail the transaction. I segue the invoice number from the CustomerVC to the InvoiceVC and it work just fine, except if the InvoiceVC is already open. This is what I have to solve.

When the InvoiceVC is open:

1. I am not sure if InvoiceVC received the segue. I have tried to print the invoice number but its equal to 0 as it was init.
2. Is there a function that can be used when the InvoiceVC is activated ( similar to viewDidLoad) that can be used when InvoiceVC receive a segue. if its already open.

Here is the code in the ClientVC:

```
@objc func tableViewDoubleClick(_ sender:AnyObject) {

if  tableView.selectedRow >= 0 {
    
    let srow = tableView.selectedRow

    fact_nb = Int(fact_tbv[srow].id_f) ?? 0  // invoice nb that you want to segue

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotofact", sender: nil)   // segue identifier

    }
}


override func prepare(for segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let sb = segue.destinationController as! FacturesVC
    print ("VCC569:", fact_nb)
    
    sb.factnb = fact_nb
}
```

This is the code in the Invoice VC:

```
class FacturesVC: NSViewController, NSTextFieldDelegate,NSComboBoxDelegate, NSTableViewDelegate {
... 
var factnb: Int = 0
...

func Load_DB( Lfact_ptr: Int) {
...  
// if factnb correspong to an InvoiceNb -  select that invoice...

if  factnb == Int(facts_list[facts_select[i]].id_f) {
            fact_ptr = facts_select[i]
            factnb = 0
        }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Once the invoice vc is open it will not receive segue. You need to keep track of the opened vc and the it the new details to display via an update or other kind of method, most likely the one you use in prepare for segue. But without any code , it is difficult to answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for tyour comment.  I have updated my question and add the code.  Hopefully. you will be able to suggest me what other king of method that are available.  Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The method post here,  using notification, have solved my problem.

https://gist.github.com/ayakix/00a38f402f4bf3efb2c8acaad94b4616